# How to add down arrow in dxdatagrid columns in blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

**Code**

How to add  down arrow in dxdatagrid columns in blazor

```
<DxDataGrid DataAsync="@ProductServices.ProductList" PageSize="5" ShowFilterRow="false" 
        RowInsertingAsync="@OnRowInserting"
        RowUpdatingAsync="@OnRowUpdating"
        RowRemovingAsync="@OnRowRemoving">
<DxDataGridCommandColumn Width="150px"></DxDataGridCommandColumn>
<DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(Product.ProductId)" Caption="ID" Width="150px"></DxDataGridColumn>
<DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(Product.ProductName)" Caption="Name" Width="150px"></DxDataGridColumn>
<DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(Product.ProdQty)" Caption="Qty" Width="150px"></DxDataGridColumn>
<DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(Product.Price)" Caption="Price" Width="150px"></DxDataGridColumn>
```

[image]

How to add  down arrow in dxdatagrid columns in blazor?

Comment: Are you trying to group something? Can you share what are you trying to group inside the product name ?

Comment: I need DropDown for Products
=========================


    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public double ProdQty { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }